# How to customise NSOutlineView in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsoutlineview, nsscrollview

I want some header for `NSOutlineView` in `NScrollview` and in every section there should be a parent and many children like below image. I want make same like shown in image. Must be Appreciated if given some tutorial links.

[image]

Please help me if anyone knows.

Comment: This is easily done with a view-based outline view (maybe with cell-based too?). If you are new to Cocoa you might find NSOutlineView has quite a steep learning curve because the data source delegate methods are more abstract than for other cocoa controls. The best practice is to wrap the views to be displayed in "node" objects. Search YouTube for "NSOutlineView".

Comment: @boyfarrell Yes I am new in Cocoa, I go through youtube video but there they given very basic. I want customisation like in image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's [SidebarDemo sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo) should contain all the features that are displayed on your screenshot:

- View based `NSOutlineView`
- Group Headers
- Custom row badges

The sample also contains row & header view designs in the .xib and a basic `NSOutlineViewDelegate` implementation in the App Delegate.